# Run two java files concurrently

Tags: java, bash, terminal

I have two java applications. They are very simple: they insert 500,000 rows of fake data into a MongoDB database and SQL database respectively. I time each operation.

How can I launch these two java files at the exact same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How exact does exact mean? Running them at *exactly* the same time is going to be damn near impossible, and fully impossible on a single-core machine (not that those still exist...).

But the easiest thing, if you want them launched very quickly, is:

```
java -jar first.jar & java -jar second.jar
```

If there's some startup time that you want to synchronize after, you could rig them both such that they busy-wait for a signal from an external event (such as a file appearing). Then start them both up, wait for them to warm up, and trigger the signal.

Comment: I only see output from first.jar using this method. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean `&`, not `&&`. The former will put the first command in the background. The latter will run the second command if the first completes successfully.

Comment: @glennjackman ah yes, good catch! thanks. Will update. gonzoc0ding: hm, I see both outputs on my terminal.

Comment: @gonzoc0ding Actually, ha, my guess is that you used my broken `&&` from before, so the second jar hadn't gotten executed yet. Try `&` instead. Sorry about that!

Comment: @gonzoc0ding, is the exit status of running first.jar non-zero?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to start them at the same time (and you can't be 100% exact). You just have to measure how much time each one executes.

If this doesn't suit you, perhaps you can setup 2 crons to start the two applications.

Comment: It is for presentation purposes, need the output to show during execution (a progress bar). I'll try two crons